# How to extract text by using imacros? Example shown

Tags: html, csv, macros, extract, imacros

How do I extract lepaux@gmail.com:ocupup

from:

```
<form id="flagform1" action="generator.php" method="POST">
<input id="flag1" name="flagalt" value="lepaux@gmail.com:ocupup
" type="hidden">
<input name="generator" value="1" type="hidden">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
<a id="copy1" data-clipboard-target="generator1" title="Copy" class="btn btn-success zeroclipboard-is-hover">Copy</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$(this).closest(&quot;form&quot;).submit();" title="Flag as invalid" class="btn btn-danger">Flag as invalid</a>
</div>
</form>
```

I've have this so far:

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=form ATTR=flag1:flagalt EXTRACT=TXT
```

But that's not working.

Comment: You may also try this way: `TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:HIDDEN FORM=ID:flagform1 ATTR=ID:flag1 EXTRACT=TXT`

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:HIDDEN ATTR=ID:flag1 EXTRACT=TXT
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```

Tested with your HTML-Code and iMacros 8.9.6 for Firefox 45.

Answer (score 0):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:HIDDEN ATTR=ID:flag1 EXTRACT=HTM
```

Comment: I edited the code. Try now. This is interesting question. Let us know if it worked.